# Object Oriented JavaScript for Canvas

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas

I have this sort of mini framework (Scene, Actor) to build upon that I got from this JS book in building a game. I will display the code here and ask the question after:

```
//-------------------------------SCENE CLASS------------------------------//

function Scene(context, width, height, images)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.images = images;
    this.actors = [];
}

Scene.prototype.register = function(actor)
{
    this.actors.push(actor);
}

Scene.prototype.unregister = function(actor)
{
    var index = this.actors.indexOf(actor);
    if(index >= 0)
    {
        this.actors.splice(index,1);
    }
}

Scene.prototype.draw = function()
{
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    for(var i = 0;i < this.actors.length; i++)
    {
        this.actors[i].draw();
    }
}

//-------------------------------ACTOR CLASS-------------------------------//

function Actor(scene, x, y)
{
    this.scene = scene;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    scene.register(this);
}

Actor.prototype.moveTo = function(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.scene.draw();
}

Actor.prototype.exit = function()
{
    this.scene.unregister(this);
    this.scene.draw();
}

Actor.prototype.draw = function()
{
    var image = this.scene.images[this.type]; // how does this work???
    this.scene.context.drawImage(image, this.x, this.y);
}

Actor.prototype.width = function()
{
    return this.scene.images[this.type].width;
}

Actor.prototype.height = function()
{
    return this.scene.images[this.type].height;
}

//-----------------------------SPACESHIP CLASS------------------------------//

function Spaceship(scene, x, y)
{
    Actor.call(this, scene, x, y);
}

Spaceship.prototype = Object.create(Actor.prototype);

Spaceship.prototype.left = function()
{
    this.moveTo(Math.max(this.x - 10, 0), this.y);
}

Spaceship.prototype.right = function()
{
    var maxWidth = this.scene.width - this.width();
    this.moveTo(Math.min(this.x + 10, maxWidth), this.y);
}

Spaceship.prototype.type = "Spaceship";
```

My question is, how do you go about plugging in images into the Scene constructor for this spaceship example or for any other actor object that may come up? It said very vaguely in the book to create a 'data table' but I am not sure how to go about it. If I wanted to utilize this class I suppose I would have to do something like this:

```
var scene = new Scene(ctx,800,600, //not sure here)
var spaceship = new Spaceship(scene,10,10);
scene.draw();
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Actor constructor is missing a `type` field. The type field is an identifier for an array of images you must pass into your scene.

In other words, you need a map from types/ids to images.

```
Actor.prototype.draw = function()
{
    var image = this.scene.images[this.type]; // how does this work???
    this.scene.context.drawImage(image, this.x, this.y);
}
```

The above function gets the image data from the image array by accessing this actor's type (which is a unique identifier). The image data is then passed to the drawImage function.

In order for this to work, every actor needs a `type`, so I've changed the following constructors:

```
// Added 'type' property to Actor
function Actor(scene, type, x, y)
{
    this.scene = scene;
    this.type = type;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    scene.register(this);
}

// Add the image type of this actor
function Spaceship(scene, x, y)
{
    Actor.call(this, 'spaceShipImageId', scene, x, y);
}
```

When setting up your scene, you need to pass in an object of image data (however the image data is stored).

Here's an example:

```
var imageData = {'spaceShipImageId': 'IMAGE_DATA...', 'planetImageId': 'DIFFERENT_IMAGE_DATA'};
var scene = new Scene(ctx, 800, 600, imageData);
var spaceship = new Spaceship(scene, 10, 10);
scene.draw();
```

Everytime a new actor is created it is automatically registered to a specific scene. The `scene.draw()` method simply draws each actor's image (based off of it's `type` property).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response! I am curious, how would you specify the IMAGE_DATA? Is this the src to the image itself?

Comment: It depends on how the scene's context class is set up. Look at that class's documentation.

Comment: So in the example you have here, you put the image in an img elment on the HTML with an id of "spaceShipImageId" right. I just don't know what you mean by IMAGE_DATA. There isn't really any documentation for the Scene class...pretty much what you see in the code example.

Comment: The drawImage function most likely takes in a img src string. Try creating an object that maps from `type`s to URLs and passing that object to your scene.